# AMPL syntax error - constraint over indexed set

Tags: indexing, set, constraints, ampl

first, here is a simple example that demonstrates my problem:

```
# .mod file
param N;
set TIME := 1 .. N;
set C ordered;
param tbar {C};
var X {C,TIME} >= 0;

minimize cost: sum {c in C} X[c,N];

subject to C1 {c in C: ord(c)>1, t in 1 .. N-1}:
    X[c,t+1] = X[c,t] + 3;
```

Here is the .dat file:

```
param N := 10;
set C := C1 C2 C3;
param tbar :=
    C1 2
    C2 3
    C3 3 ;
```

I get the syntax error

```
test.mod, line 9 (offset 142):
    syntax error
context:  subject to C1 {c in C:  >>> ord(c)>1, <<<  t in 1 .. N-1}:
```

If I change the position of the indexing to

```
{t in 1 .. N-1, c in C: ord(c)>1},
```

it works fine. The problem is, that I want to have

```
{c in C: ord(c)>1, t in tbar[c] .. N-1},
```

so I cannot change the position.
Does anybody know why this error happens and if there is a way around it?

Comment: I found the solution. the condition has to be at the end: {c in C, t in tbar[c] .. N-1: ord(c)>1} works.

Comment: Another option here is to express it without a condition. Something like {c in (C diff {first(C)}), t in tbar[c] .. N-1} should work. In this example it probably doesn't much matter which version you choose, but for large index sets it might be more efficient to eliminate those cases immediately rather than generating them and then removing again via the condition.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found out already, the condition should be at the end of the indexing expression:

```
subject to C1 {c in C, t in 1 .. N-1: ord(c)>1}:
    X[c,t+1] = X[c,t] + 3;
```

If you want to use `c` as a subscript in a later expression such as `tbar[c]` and it is not defined for `c = first(C)` then you can do

```
{c in (C diff {first(C)}), t in tbar[c] .. N-1}
```

as suggested by Geoffrey Brent.